# Can a Spring Cloud Gateway App be Enabled as a Cloud Config Server?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to enable a Spring Cloud Gateway app to automatically refresh its routing config yml on the fly. I have been able to set up a Cloud Config server to host the route YAML and enabled the Spring Cloud Gateway to automatically refresh its config via a `@Scheduled` `contextRefresher.refresh()` usage.  However, this requires two running apps, and we want to try to minimize the number of additional servers needed to support this requirement.

The Spring Cloud Config Server documentation suggests any boot app can be embedded with a config server via the `@EnableConfigServer` annotation: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_spring_cloud_config_server

However, when attempting to introduce the `spring-cloud-config-server` module in my Gateway's build.gradle, I run into the following error on startup:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

From the discussion here (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/319) it seems that the issue above arises because spring-boot-starter-web is incompatible w/ Gateway; Gateway is a Netty app and spring-boot-starter-web uses tomcat/servlets.  When trying to exclude `spring-boot-starter-web` from the cloud-config-server module, the app fails again w/:

`onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Is it the case that a Spring Cloud Gateway app cannot be enabled as a CloudConfig server? Or am I missing something. 
 FWIW my sprincCloudVersion is `Finchley.SR1`

Answer (score 0):

They can not. Config server is based on spring MVC (servlets), gateway is based on spring webflux and Netty. They are not compatible and cannot be run together.